# Export and ImportValue in another stack under sub

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I am trying to get a value from one stack to another using the below syntax.

stack one-

```
Outputs:
  CompRestAPI:
    Description: Rest Api Id
    Value: !Ref CompRestAPI
    Export:
      Name: 'CompRestAPI'
```

Stack two -

```
CompRestApiWaf:
    Type: AWS::WAFv2::WebACLAssociation
    DependsOn: CompApiGatewayStage
    Properties:
      RestApiId: !ImportValue 'CompRestAPI'
      ResourceArn: !Sub 'arn:aws:apigateway:${REGION}:/${RestApiId}/${STAGENAME}-apistage'
      WebACLArn: !Ref WafId
```

I am able to get the values for other resources using 1st syntax, but I am not able to get the value for RestApiId under !Sub

`RestApiId: !ImportValue 'CompRestAPI'`

`ResourceArn: !Sub 'arn:aws:apigateway:${REGION}:/${RestApiId}/apistage'`

So is there any way to use !ImportValue under !Sub condition?

I tried it using below code, validation is pass but still showing me an error
Error reason: The ARN isn't valid. A valid ARN begins with arn: and includes other information separated by colons or slashes., field: RESOURCE_ARN, parameter:

```
 CompRestApiWaf:
    Type: AWS::WAFv2::WebACLAssociation
    DependsOn: CompApiGatewayStage
    Properties:
      ResourceArn: !Sub 'arn:aws:apigateway:${REGION}:/{!ImportValue CompRestAPI}/stages/apistage'
      WebACLArn: !Ref WafId
```

Answer (score 0):

I am done with it using Fn::join:

```
SourceArn: 
    Fn::Join: 
    - ""
    - - 'arn:aws:execute-api:'
      - !Ref AWS::Region
      - ':'
      - !Ref AWS::AccountId
      - ':'
      - !Ref ApiGatewayRestApiResource
      - '/*'
```

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/29895505)

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
ResourceArn: !Sub
  - 'arn:aws:apigateway:${REGION}:/${CompRestAPI}/stages/apistage'
  - CompRestAPI: !ImportValue CompRestAPI
```

you can expand the second parameter to have multiple keys for multiple imports like so

```
SecretString: !Sub
  - 'postgres://${username}:${password}@${dbhost}:${dbport}/${dbname}'
  - username: !Ref 'DBUser'
    password: !Ref 'DBPassword'
    dbhost: !Ref DbMasterDnsEntry
    dbport: !GetAtt AuroraPgCluster.Endpoint.Port
    dbname: !Ref 'DBName'
```